# Gameobject's collider doesn't work when rotate

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have two gameObjects each of them have a PolygonCollider2D, but the PolygonCollider2D isn't working and falling through the other one when rotate one of them.

Comment: Do they have also a Rigidbody attached?

Comment: of course they have !